# Thousand separator in excell with Epplus for mobile

Tags: excel, export, currency, epplus

I export excel file with Epplus and make `string CurrencyFormat = "#,##0.00";` for thousand separator. It's work well on android,windows mobile but on Iphone it show normal number format not my costume format. Thanks for your help.